# This site looks confused

Tags: discussion, meta

The "parent" site has this in right at the top before any questions:

> VOTE NOW: What should be done with questions asking for game recommendations?

But when you click on the link, you go to a question that has this at the bottom of the question:

> Closed as subjective and argumentative

So... we want feed back on a closed question?  (Closed questions have an inherent connotation of being inappropriate for the site.)

It looks like those that run the "Parent" site are fighting with those that run the meta site.

If that what is happening (or that is the message that is trying to be sent) then we can watch and see who wins.

Otherwise it may be a good idea to not have the the question closed.  (If you are trying to not allow more answers then Lock it, don't close it.  I have seen locked questions on StackOverflow, so I assume it can be done here too.  Though I don't know if that allows more voting.)

Ether way, what ever is done or not done, it is confusing to be referred (by the site) to a closed question.

Comment: We can lock, but only moderators can do that. If done to the question, it would indeed prevent new answers from accumulating but still allow activity on existing answers.

Comment: @Grace Locking prevents voting, I'm afraid? You certainly can't vote on locked answers.

Comment: @badp You can lock the *question* but still vote on the answers. If the answer is locked, it can't be voted on.

Comment: By the way, Vaccano, even though the answer is closed you can technically still vote on the answers.

Answer (score 5):

5 users decided to [throw away the attempt at policy making](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1482/final-game-rec-showdown-preparation) Oak tried to make and [the resulting question](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1491) because [an unimplementable answer attracted large consensus.](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1491/what-should-be-done-with-questions-asking-for-game-recommendations/1493#1493) In some of these users' opinion, the only way to truly exclude this poll is to start over.

> I have to be honest, this vote was not conducted with enough preparation and for-planning and the result has been disastrous. I'm going to have to ask, at this time, that we abandon this vote and reconvene when we have a better understanding of what it is that we want to accomplish, and a better method for doing so. – tzenes yesterday

Frankly, I disagree for a number of simple reasons:

- There was a time and a place to prepare and that time and place are now well over.
- Users can vote on multiple answers, so you do *not* necessarily discount users by discounting an answer.
- The whole point of this poll is that the current situation is unacceptable. Voting to keep the situation basically as-is, thus, is unacceptable.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is a lot of confusion going on. We promised a vote to determine our policy for game recommendations, a vote scheduled to run for 3 weeks and end on December 23rd.

However, one week into the process, two of the policies were attempted to be withdrawn. Not many people notice the second one because it had minimal support and was actually deleted. The big problem is the first policy to be withdrawn, which was one of the popular choices in the currently running vote.

There is argument about whether it is right to continue onwards with the vote even after the votes on those two answers have been effectively discounted. Those who believe that the withdrawal of the policies is tantamount to breaking the entire poll have decided to vote to close the poll, and propose that a new one is made after yet more preparation is done.

We could possibly take down the system message for now. I'm not exactly happy with that, as it could end up in some sort of flip-flop.

Comment: +1 for removing the system message